# Should we rename the sr4.matrix tag to sr4-matrix?

Tags: discussion, tags

We have this tag on the main site: [sr4.matrix](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sr4.matrix)

Should it be renamed to [sr4-matrix](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sr4-matrix)?

Tag naming convention suggests that spaces should be hyphens, not dots, and I can't find any particular reason why it would explicitly use a dot.

Comment: What is sr4.matrix and how's it different from shadowrun-sr4?

Comment: @mxyzplk Personally I have no idea.

Comment: I'm guessing it's used to specifically describe the matrix as it relates to shadowrun 4e (which changed a lot from 3e due to the crash...), but I'm not certain it warrants its own tag. The Matrix is big and complicated though, so maybe?

Comment: Apparently there once existed [tag:sr4.shadowrun] which is now [a synonym](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/tags/shadowrun-sr4/synonyms) of [tag:shadowrun-sr4], which might explain why a [tag:sr4.matrix] tag exists.

Comment: I only made the sr5-matrix tag because I noticed lots of questions about it (that part is so poorly written) and the sr4-matrix tag came to my attention, I figured since it'd been around a while that it was within guidelines and so used it to justify the new tag.  If that was incorrect, feel free to get rid of that one, too.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest that it be renamed to [virtual-reality](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/virtual-reality).

The Matrix of Shadowrun and the Matrix Trilogy are examples of virtual reality, as is the cyberspace of Ghost in the Shell. Matrix is just the Shadowrun setting's name for the overarching concept.

As wax eagle has said in chat, tags should be applicable across multiple games.

> @JonathanHobbs concepts in games should be tagged separately so they can be used across multiple games. if another game has a matrix concept the same matrix can be applied and differentiated with the system tag.
>
> [wax eagle's chat comment](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/6690999#6690999)