# Retag [sr4.matrix] to [sr4-matrix]

Tags: support, status-completed, tags

Can we make [sr4.matrix](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sr4.matrix) a synonym of [sr4-matrix](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sr4-matrix), creating the latter in the process? (Or just retag all the [sr4.matrix](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sr4.matrix) questions)

The former doesn't follow our tag convention. [There is no reason it uses the dot](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1667/1204), other than at some point a bunch of tags used the dot and now they don't. (Turns out I asked about this myself over a year ago; this time I'm making the actual request!)

Answer (score 3):

Your wish is my command...

Or something like that.